# KeePassX "Unable to open the database. Wrong key or database file is corrupt."

Tags: keepassx

Trying to open a .kdbx database with correct password gives the following error "Unable to open the database. Wrong key or database file is corrupt". However, it does work on OSX. Repairing does not fix the issue. I remember also having few random successes before but that's about it.

Comment: Are you sure you have the proper password? Do you use a keyfile? You should compare the hashes on both machines, or copy again. Also check keyboard layout.

Comment: Also Note: Be sure you are coping over the Key file as well. 2 Factor Protection so just anyone can't open your database.

Comment: @davidbaumann yup, checked it all, still the problem persists.

Comment: I have the same problem. 100% sure the password is correct.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error. [This answer on GitHub](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/313) was the solution for me:

> You always need to use ALL keys you used for creating the database. When you create a database with password and key file, you need to use both to unlock it. Make sure the corresponding checkboxes are ticked on the unlock screen.

Comment: oh my god lol. So I had the wrong checkbox set :) (I had to uncheck the keyfile)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and somehow it is corrupted on every copy of the file i've got.. How is that even possible?  I know it is the right password, as i have used in 10 years. And i got a lot of backups, but none of the backups work.

Can it be the program?? any updates that could make it useless?

Edit: It is only the latest copy that is corrupted, the older ones had a different password :D

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? If you have a question ask it in the proper way not trying to slip it in as an answer.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1203398)